# Extending a class with instance method

Tags: swift

I'm trying to extend the functionality of a existing type in Swift. I want to use dot syntax to call the methods on the type.

I want to say:

```
existingType.example.someMethod()
existingType.example.anotherMethod()
```

I'm currently using an extension like so:

```
extension ExistingType {
    func someMethod() {
    }
    func anotherMethod() {
    }
}

existingType.someMethod()
existingType.anotherMethod()
```

Doing this will expose too many functions. So, I want to write these methods in a class, and just extend the ExistingType to use an instance of the class. I'm not sure the right way to go about this.

if I were actually implementing the existing type, I would do the following:

```
struct ExistingType {

    var example = Example()
}

struct Example {
    func someMethod() {
    }

    func anotherMethod() {
    }
}
```

Allowing me to call the methods by:

```
let existingType = ExistingType()
existingType.example.someMethod()
```

The issue is I'm not implementing the type, because it already exists. I just need to extend it.

Comment: Can you give an example using actual meaningful classes and methods, maybe that way we can pick up what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add another property `example` the existing class `ExistingType` and call methods of that property. You cannot add properties in extensions, though. The only way to add another property to the existing class is to subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `struct`.

```
struct NewType {
    let existingType: ExistingType

    func someMethod() {
    }

    func anotherMethod() {
    }
}
```